GCP windows public images
anyone know why google has not updated their windows family public images to coincide with
Microsoft patch Tuesday. I've checked images in GCP console and all the windows images still have July date. As of today 8/19/2024 it has not been updated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
